# Registrars who forward email without filtering?

Tags: email, gmail, domain, godaddy, registrar

I currently have my personal domain forwarded to my gmail account.  Unfortunately, many emails to my domain are being incorrectly blocked by the registrar's mail agent's spam filter.  I have tried GoDaddy and NameSilo so far.  I have searched, but been unable to find a registrar who will forward all email without filtering.

I do not have a static IP address, so running my own SMTP server is not an option.

Can anyone recommend a registrar who will forward all email without filtering?

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Answer (score 2):

If such a registrar existed, it would exist only temporarily. GMail would block it for forwarding spam, and then it would cease to be useful. You may be able to find such a service if you don't insist on having them forward your mail to GMail.

The other problem is that users tend to be too stupid to use such a service. For example, they keep hitting the "report spam" button on forwarded spam even though *they* are the sender of these emails and are reporting *themselves*. This causes all kinds of problems for anyone trying to operate such a service.

Comment: Even though the email is "forwarded", the headers still contain the full origin path, right?  Why would Google mark the relayer as spam when the origin is known?

Comment: @sjLonghorn Google's not trying to police the world, just their mail system. If you create spam on system A and send it to system B, so long as neither A nor B are Google, it's not something Google is going to try to police. But if you send spam to Google, that's a different story. (And those headers can be faked anyway.)